# What’s happening in this code with Number objects holding properties and incrementing the number?

Tags: javascript

[A recent tweet](https://twitter.com/weitzelb/status/718623065480019968) contained this snippet of JavaScript.

Can someone please explain what is happening in it step by step?

```
> function dis() { return this }
undefined
> five = dis.call(5)
Number {[[PrimitiveValue]]: 5}
> five.wtf = 'potato'
"potato"
> five.wtf
"potato"
> five * 5
25
> five.wtf
"potato"
> five++
5
> five.wtf
undefined
> five.wtf = 'potato?'
"potato?"
> five.wtf
undefined
> five
6
```

In particular, it is not clear to me:

- why the result of `dis.call(5)` is a `Number` with some kind of a `[[PrimitiveValue]]` property, but the results of `five++` and `five * 5` appear to just be the plain numbers `5` and `25` (not `Number`s)
- why the `five.wtf` property disappears after the `five++` increment
- why the `five.wtf` property is no longer even settable after the `five++` increment, despite the `five.wtf = 'potato?'` assignment apparently setting the value.

Comment: Haha I saw that tweet!! It it so bizarre, I think because you multiply it, it doesn't quite affect the object, but `++` seems to affect the underlying type

Comment: Which line you did not understand ? `Pre` vs `Post` increment ? After multiplication, It is again a `Number` object which does not have `wtf` property...But still it is an `object` hence it can have `properties`..

Comment: @Rayon No, I think it's something to do with the increment operator and primitives vs objects.

Comment: @Rayon And which also refuses to "accept" a new `.wtf` property...!?

Comment: Wait a minute, `five * 5` doesn't affect the five. Once you increment it, you change five from an object to a number. simple

Comment: @Rayon I don't understand nearly any of it. Eg - what is `Number {[[PrimitiveValue]]: 5}`, why is it returned when I give `5` to a function that expects no arguments, why is it not `=== 5` (not shown in the snippet), why does it allow itself to have properties set? I understand that `five * 5` does not modify the variable `five`, whereas `five++` is like saying `five = five + 1`. That part is fine.

Comment: When you call `dis` with `dis.call(5)`, this wraps the primitive number `5` into an object of type `Number` that contains the `5`, so that this object can be returned as `this` object. The `++` converts it back to a primitive number that can't contain properties, so `wtf` begins to be undefined.

Comment: @GSerg – True... [___and primitive values will be converted to objects___](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call#Parameters)

Comment: @Rayon ... and that [has changed with ES6](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-function.prototype.call). So going forward this whole thing will stop happening.

Comment: @GSerg It's not a change in ES6; that [change was made in ES5](https://es5.github.io/#x15.3.4.4). The problem persists because, per NOTE 1, "Even though the *thisArg* is passed without modification, non-strict functions still perform these transformations upon entry to the function." This refers to [OrdinaryCallBindThis](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ordinarycallbindthis) (used during [[Call]]) which does a ToObject `this` coercion for non-strict functions. The change in ES5 said coercion doesn't happen *during* `.call`, but it does happen generally, even with `.call`.

Comment: The steps in OrdinaryCallBindThis also exists in ES5, though it is contained in a section entitled [Entering Function Code](https://es5.github.io/#x10.4.3). Like OrdinaryCallBindThis, the ES5 steps are used as part of [[Call]]. -- In sum, this whole thing already *did* stop happening, a long time ago, but only if you use strict mode function.

Comment: I might be a little late here, but am I the only one who looks at this without batting an eyelash and says _"Yup I get it. JavaScript."_ There's really only one advanced(ish) concept here and that's objects vs. primitives, it doesn't seem that difficult to me.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts No, you're not. But we're meant to be *helping* Nathan, not commenting "that's just JavaScript, it's not that difficult for *me*". (I know you have made some useful comments on the answers, but this one isn't.)

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I apologize that it's an unuseful comment, I'm just baffled as to why this has so many upvotes, other than being related to something that was posted on twitter and is mildly humorous.

Comment: @wizzwizz4: We also have a duty of curation. I don't see that this question is of much value for the Stack Overflow database. Like most of the high-voted questions :)

Comment: Object wrappers for primitives are one of the worst parts of JavaScript and should never have existed. Strict mode helps with this a little, anyway, by not object-ifying `this` and by throwing errors when failing to assign to properties.

Comment: @CallumLinington the `++` performs type coercion ;) might help to explain

Answer (score 279, accepted):

OP here. Funny to see this on Stack Overflow :)

Before stepping through the behaviour, its important to clarify a few things:

1. [Number value](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.19) and [Number object](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.21) (`a = 3` vs `a = new Number(3)`) are very different. One is a primitive, the other is an object. You cannot assign attributes to primitives, but you can to objects.
2. Coercion between the two is implicit.

   For example:

   ```
   (new Number(3) === 3)  // returns false
   (new Number(3) == 3)   // returns true, as the '==' operator coerces
   (+new Number(3) === 3) // returns true, as the '+' operator coerces
   ```
3. Every [Expression](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11) has a return value. When the [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) reads and executes an expression, this is what it displays. The return values often don't mean what you think and imply things that just aren't true.

Ok, here we go.

[image: Original image of the JavaScript code]

#### *The pledge.*

```
> function dis() { return this }
undefined
> five = dis.call(5)
[Number: 5]
```

Define a function `dis` and [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) it with `5`. This will execute the function with `5` as the context (`this`). Here it is coerced from a Number value to a Number object. It is very important to note that were we in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) **this would not have happened**.

```
> five.wtf = 'potato'
'potato'
> five.wtf
'potato'
```

Now we set the attribute `five.wtf` to `'potato'`, and with five as an object, sure enough it accepts the [Simple Assignment](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.13.1).

```
> five * 5
25
> five.wtf
'potato'
```

With `five` as an object, I ensure it can still perform simple arithmetic operations. It can. Do its attributes still stick? Yes.

#### *The turn.*

```
> five++
5
> five.wtf
undefined
```

Now we check `five++`. The trick with [postfix increment](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.3) is that the entire expression will evaluate against the original value *and then* increment the value. It looks like `five` is still five, but really the expression evaluated to five, then set `five` to `6`.

Not only did `five` get set to `6`, but it was coerced back into a Number value, and all attributes are lost. Since primitives cannot hold attributes, `five.wtf` is undefined.

```
> five.wtf = 'potato?'
'potato?'
> five.wtf
undefined
```

I again attempt to reassign an attribute `wtf` to `five`. The return value implies it sticks, but it in fact does not because `five` is a Number value, not a Number object. The expression evaluates to `'potato?'`, but when we check we see it was not assigned.

#### *The prestige.*

```
> five
6
```

Ever since the postfix increment, `five` has been `6`.

Comment: Are you watching closely?

Comment: Awesome. :) Any idea why we have both kinds of numbers?

Comment: @Nathan Long Well, in Java, which JavaScript borrowed heavily from in the beginning, all primitives have a class equivalent. `int` and `Integer`, for example. I assume this is so you can create a function `doSomething(Object)`, and still be able to give it primitives. Primitives will be converted to their corresponding classes in this case. But JS doesn't really care about types, so the reason is probably something else

Comment: Why does `five++` show `5` instead of `[Number: 5]` (the original value of `five` before the post-increment).

Comment: @Eric The first thing [`++` does is apply ToNumber to the value](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-postfix-increment-operator-runtime-semantics-evaluation). Compare a similar case with strings: if you have `x="5"`, then `x++` returns the number `5`.

Comment: Really the magic all happens at `dis.call(5)`, the coercion to object, I would never have expected that.

Comment: @NathanLong the design "why": all operations on primitives are defined on the corresponding function prototype for that `type`. This allows it to wrap behavior for all `Number`s,`+/- Infinity`, and `NaN`. The historic "why": this implementation is modeled after Java's [Autoboxing and Unboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html), even though the two languages are fundamentally **very** different.

Comment: @mcfedr You could also replace the first two lines with `five = new Number(5)`.

Comment: near the end, would it be more correct to say that "all attributes are lost" not (just) because it was coerced into a value, but (also) because you have completely changed objects (values)? even if it weren't coerced into a value, you still would have lost `.wtf` because five is now a different object than it was before (6). Or it's possible this is completely wrong and the opposite is true: `wtf` was lost *only* because you unboxed, but I suspect not.

Comment: `It looks like five is still five, but really the expression evaluated to five, then set five to 6.`

I came here to write exactly that. `five++` is not the same as `++five`.

Comment: @Suppen, JavaScript has zero relationship to Java expect some marketing droid took the Java name and attached it on. So no, JavaScript did **NOT** borrow from Java. It's its own language, no relation to Java whatsoever.

Comment: Having similar names doesn't stop them being related. JavaScript was clearly influenced by Java, and both by C. Java didn't have autoboxing until 2004, but it did have the primitive vs object distinction when JavaScript was created. See: https://brendaneich.com/2008/04/popularity/

Comment: @gman - That's pure disinformation.  Yes, they're different languages.  No, that doesn't mean Java didn't influence JavaScript's design... the original plan for it was to be a functional language with a design similar to Scheme, but Eich was instructed to make it more similar to Java for marketing reasons, so the language was (partially) redesigned with a Java-like makeover.

Comment: @Jules, that influence is about as important to JavaScript as saying it uses ascii for keywords just like Java. Or uses infix expressions just like Java. In other words effectively zero influence. There's so little influence from Java it's anti-useful, even arguably mis-leading to even mention it. Nothing about Java is relatable to JavaScript and bringing it up when taking about JavaScrip only serves to confuse learners of JavaScript

Comment: @paulpro that's the thing, if it was `new Number`it clear what's happening, but that coercion is completely unexpected

Comment: @gman except that there are many much more detailed influences, including the naming of large chunks of its standard library, the behaviour of standard object types, and even the fact that it uses a braces-and-semicolons syntax (even if the semicolons are optional) derives from the fact that it was designed to be familiar to Java programmers.  Yes, it's confusing to beginners.  That doesn't mean the influences don't exist.

Comment: "The return value implies it sticks, but it in fact does not because five is a Number value, not a Number object. The expression evaluates to 'potato?', but when we check we see it was not assigned." For me, this is a big WTF. It's like, "this value is not the sort that can have properties assigned, but I won't give you an error if you try, I'll just pretend it worked and forget the value. Yay I'm Javascript!"

Comment: And then, it turns out, that the next time you type the exact sequence of letters f-i-v-e after reading this post, all your bases are @Matthew

Answer (score 77):

There are two different ways to represent a number:

```
var a = 5;
var b = new Number(5);
```

The first is a primitive, the second an object. For all intents and purposes both behave the same, except they look different when printed to the console. One important difference is that, as an object, `new Number(5)` accepts new properties just like any plain `{}`, while the primitive `5` does not:

```
a.foo = 'bar';  // doesn't stick
b.foo = 'bar';  // sticks
```

As for the initial `dis.call(5)` part, please see [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3127429/476). Let's just say that the first argument to `call` is used as the value of `this`, and that this operation forces the number into the more complex `Number` object form.* Later on `++` forces it back into the primitive form, because the addition operation `+` results in a new primitive.

```
> five = dis.call(5)  // for all intents and purposes same as new Number(5)
Number {[[PrimitiveValue]]: 5}
> five.wtf = 'potato'
"potato"
> five.wtf
"potato"
```

A `Number` object accepts new properties.

```
> five++
```

`++` results in a new primitive `6` value...

```
> five.wtf
undefined
> five.wtf = 'potato?'
"potato?"
> five.wtf
undefined
```

...which does not have and does not accept custom attributes.

* Note that in *strict mode* the `this` argument would be treated differently and would *not* be converted to a `Number`. See http://es5.github.io/#x10.4.3 for the implementation details.

Comment: @Pharap sure way better in C/C++ where you can do `#define true false`. Or in Java, where you can just redefine what numbers mean. These are good solid languages. In truth, every language has similar "tricks" where you get a result that works as intended but may look odd.

Comment: @Vld Ok let me rephrase that, this is why I hate duck typing.

Answer (score 59):

**There's Coercion in the JavaScript World - A Detective Story**

Nathan, you have no idea what you've uncovered.

I've been investigating this for weeks now. It all started on a stormy night last October. I accidentally stumbled upon the `Number` class - I mean, why in the world did JavaScript have a `Number` class?

I wasn't prepared for what I was going to find out next.

It turns out that JavaScript, without telling you, has been changing your numbers to objects and your objects to numbers right under your nose.

JavaScript was hoping no one would catch on, but people have been reporting strange unexpected behavior, and now thanks to you and your question I have the evidence I need to blow this thing wide open.

This is what we've found out so far. I don't know if I should even be telling you this - you might want to turn off your JavaScript.

```
> function dis() { return this }
undefined
```

When you created that function, you probably had no idea what was going to happen next. Everything looked fine, and everything was fine - for now.

No error messages, just the word "undefined" in console output, exactly what you would expect. After all, this was a function declaration - it isn't supposed to return anything.

But this was just the beginning. What happened next, no one could have predicted.

```
> five = dis.call(5)
Number {[[PrimitiveValue]]: 5}
```

Yeah I know, you expected a `5`, but that's not what you got, was it - you got something else - something different.

The same thing happened to me.

I didn't know what to make of it. It drove me nuts. I couldn't sleep, I couldn't eat, I tried to drink it away, but no amount of Mountain Dew would make me forget. It just didn't make any sense!

That's when I found out what was really going on - it was coercion, and it was happening right there in front of my eyes, but I was too blind to see it.

Mozilla tried to bury it by putting it where they knew nobody would look - their [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).

After hours of recursively reading and re-reading and re-re-reading I found this:

> "... and primitive values will be converted to objects."

It was right there plain as can be spelled out in Open Sans font. It was the `call()` function - how could I be so stupid?!

My number was no longer a number at all. The moment I passed it into `call()`, it became something else. It became... an object.

I couldn't believe it at first. How could this be true? But I couldn't ignore the evidence that was mounting up around me. It's right there if you just look:

```
> five.wtf = 'potato'
"potato"

> five.wtf
"potato"
```

`wtf` was right. Numbers can't have custom properties - we all know that! It's the first thing they teach you at the academy.

We should have known the moment we saw the console output - this was not the number we thought it was. This was an impostor - an object passing itself off as our sweet innocent number.

This was... `new Number(5)`.

Of course! It made perfect sense. `call()` had a job to do, he had to invoke a function, and to do that he needed to populate `this`, he knew he couldn't do that with a number - he needed an object and he was willing to do anything to get it, even if that meant coercing our number. When `call()` saw the number `5`, he saw an opportunity.

It was the perfect plan: wait until no one was looking and swap out our number for an object that looks just like it. We get a number, the function gets invoked, and no one would be the wiser.

It really was the perfect plan, but like all plans, even perfect ones, there was a hole in it, and we were about to fall right into it.

See, what `call()` didn't understand was that he wasn't the only one in town who could coerce numbers. This was JavaScript after all - coercion was everywhere.

`call()` took my number, and I wasn't going to stop until I pulled the mask off of his little impostor and expose him to the whole Stack Overflow community.

But how? I needed a plan. Sure it looks like a number, but I know it's not, there's gotta be a way to prove that. That's it! It *looks* like a number, but can it act like one?

I told `five` I need him to become 5 times larger - he didn't ask why and I didn't explain. I then did what any good programmer would do: I multiplied. Surely there was no way he could fake his way out of this.

```
> five * 5
25
> five.wtf
'potato'
```

Damn it! Not only did `five` multiply just fine `wtf` was still there. Damn this guy and his potato.

What the hell was going on? Was I wrong about this whole thing? Is `five` really a number? No, I must be missing something, I know it, there's something I must be forgetting, something so simple and basic that I'm completely overlooking it.

This was not looking good, I had been writing this answer for hours and I was still no closer to making my point. I couldn't keep this up, eventually people would stop reading, I had to think of something and I had to think of it fast.

Wait that's it! `five` wasn't 25, 25 was the result, 25 was a completely different number. Of course, how could I forget? Numbers are immutable. When you multiply `5 * 5` nothing gets assigned to anything you just create a new number `25`.

That must be what's happening here. Somehow when I multiply `five * 5`, `five` must be getting coerced into a number and that number must be the one used for the multiplication. It's the results of that multiplication that gets printed to the console, not the value of `five` itself. `five` never gets assigned anything - so of course it doesn't change.

So then how do I get `five` to assign himself the result of an operation. I got it. Before `five` even had a chance to think, I yelled "++".

```
> five++
5
```

Aha! I had him! Everybody knows `5 + 1` is `6`, this was the evidence I needed to expose that `five` was not a number! It was an impostor! A bad impostor that didn't know how to count. And I could prove it. Here's how a real number acts:

```
> num = 5
5
> num++
5
```

Wait? What was going on here? *sigh* I got so caught up in busting `five` that I forget how post operators work. When I use the `++` at the end of `five` I'm saying return the current value, then increment `five`. It's the value *before* the operation occurs that gets printed to the console. `num` was in fact `6` and I could prove it:

```
>num
6
```

Time to see what `five` really was:

```
>five
6
```

...it was exactly what it should be. `five` was good - but I was better. If `five` were still an object that would mean it would still have the property `wtf` and I was willing to bet everything it didn't.

```
> five.wtf
undefined
```

Aha! I was right. I had him! `five` was a number now - it wasn't an object anymore. I knew the multiplication trick wouldn't save it this time. See `five++` is really `five = five + 1`. Unlike the multiplication, the `++` operator assigns a value to `five`. More specifically, it assigns it the results of `five + 1` which just like in the case of multiplication returns a new immutable **number**.

I knew I had him, and just to make sure he couldn't squirm his way out of it. I had one more test up my sleeve. If I was right, and `five` was really a number now, then this wouldn't work:

```
> five.wtf = 'potato?'
'potato?'
```

He wasn't going to fool me this time. I knew `potato?` was going to be printed to the console because that's output of the assignment. The real question is, will `wtf` still be there?

```
> five.wtf
undefined
```

Just as I suspected - nothing - because numbers can't be assigned properties. We learned that the first year at the academy ;)

Thanks Nathan. Thanks to your courage in asking this question I can finally put all this behind me and move on to a new case.

Like this one about the function `toValue()`. Oh dear god. Nooo!

Comment: Forget it Jake; it's Javascript.

Comment: Why do we call constructor functions "classes" in JS?

Answer (score 27):

```
01 > function dis() { return this }
02 undefined
03 > five = dis.call(5)
04 Number {[[PrimitiveValue]]: 5}
05 > five.wtf = 'potato'
06 "potato"
07 > five.wtf
08 "potato"
09 > five * 5
10 25
11 > five.wtf
12 "potato"
13 > five++
14 5
15 > five.wtf
16 undefined
17 > five.wtf = 'potato?'
18 "potato?"
19 > five.wtf
20 undefined
21 > five
22 6
```

`01` declares a function `dis` that returns the context object. What `this` represents changes depending on whether you're using strict mode or not. The entire example has different results if the function were declared as:

```
> function dis() { "use strict"; return this }
```

This is detailed in [section 10.4.3 in the ES5 specification](http://es5.github.io/#x10.4.3)

> 1. If the function code is strict code, set the ThisBinding to thisArg.
> 2. Else if thisArg is null or undefined, set the ThisBinding to the global object.
> 3. Else if Type(thisArg) is not Object, set the ThisBinding to ToObject(thisArg).

`02` is the return value of the function declaration. `undefined` should be self explanatory here.

`03` the variable `five` is initialized with the return value of `dis` when called in the context of the primitive value `5`. Because `dis` is not in strict mode, this line is identical to calling `five = Object(5)`.

`04` The odd `Number {[[PrimitiveValue]]: 5}` return value is the representation of the object that wraps the primitive value `5`

`05` the `five` object's `wtf` property is assigned a string value of `'potato'`

`06` is the return value of the assignment and should be self explanatory.

`07` the `five` object's `wtf` property is being examined

`08` as `five.wtf` was previously set to `'potato'` it returns `'potato'` here

`09` the `five` object is being multiplied by the primitive value `5`. This is no different from any other object being multiplied and is explained in [section 11.5 of the ES5 specification](http://es5.github.io/#x11.5). Of particular note is how objects are cast to numeric values, which is covered in a few sections.

[9.3 ToNumber](http://es5.github.io/#x9.3):

> 1. Let primValue be ToPrimitive(input argument, hint Number).
> 2. Return ToNumber(primValue).

[9.1 ToPrimitive](http://es5.github.io/#x9.1):

> Return a default value for the Object. The default value of an object is retrieved by calling the [[DefaultValue]] internal method of the object, passing the optional hint PreferredType. The behaviour of the [[DefaultValue]] internal method is defined by this specification for all native ECMAScript objects in [8.12.8](http://es5.github.io/#x8.12.8).

[8.12.8 [[DefaultValue]]](http://es5.github.io/#x8.12.8):

> Let valueOf be the result of calling the [[Get]] internal method of object O with argument "valueOf".
>
> 1. If IsCallable(valueOf) is true then,
>
>    1. Let val be the result of calling the [[Call]] internal method of valueOf, with O as the this value and an empty argument list.
>    2. If val is a primitive value, return val.

This is all a roundabout way of saying that the object's `valueOf` function gets called and the return value from that function is used in the equation. If you were to change the `valueOf` function you could change the results of the operation:

```
> five.valueOf = function () { return 10 }
undefined
> five * 5
50
```

`10` as `five`s `valueOf` function was unchanged, it returns the wrapped primitive value `5` so that `five * 5` evaluates to `5 * 5` which results in `25`

`11` the `five` object's `wtf` property is evaluated *again* despite having been unchanged from when it was assigned on `05`.

`12` `'potato'`

`13` the [Postfix Increment Operator](http://es5.github.io/#x11.3.1) is called on `five`, which gets the numeric value (`5`, we covered how earlier), stores the value so that it can be returned, adds `1` to the value (`6`), assigns the value to `five`, and returns the stored value (`5`)

`14` as before, the returned value is the value before it was incremented

`15` the `wtf` property of the primitive value (`6`) stored at the variable `five` is accessed. [Section 15.7.5 of the ES5 specification](http://es5.github.io/#x15.7.5) defines this behavior. Numbers get the properties from `Number.prototype`.

`16` `Number.prototype` doesn't have a `wtf` property, so `undefined` is returned

`17` `five.wtf` is assigned a value of `'potato?'`. [Assignment is defined in 11.13.1 of the ES5 specification](http://es5.github.io/#x11.13.1). Basically the value assigned is returned but not stored.

`18` `'potato?'` was returned by the assignment operator

`19` again `five`, which has a value of `6` is accessed, and again `Number.prototype` doesn't have a `wtf` property

`20` `undefined` as explained above

`21` `five` is accessed

`22` `6` is returned as explained in `13`

Answer (score 17):

It's pretty simple.

```
function dis () { return this; }
```

This returns the `this` context. So, if you do `call(5)` you're passing the number as an object.

The `call` function doesn't supply arguments, the first argument you give is the context of `this`. Usually if you want it on it's on context, you give it `{}` so `dis.call({})`, which means `this` in the function is an empty `this`. However, if you pass `5` it seems it will be converted to an object. See [.call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call#Parameters)

So the return is `object`

When you do `five * 5`, JavaScript sees the object `five` as the primitive type, so is equivalent to `5 * 5`. Interestingly, do `'5' * 5`, it still equals `25`, so JavaScript is clearly casting under the hood. **No changes to the underlying `five` type is done on this line**

But when you do `++` it will convert the object to the primitive `number` type thus removing the `.wtf` property. **Because you are affecting the underlying type**

Comment: The return is [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number).

Comment: `++` converts and assigns it back. `++` is equal to `variable = variable + 1`. So you loose `wtf`

Comment: The `*` vs `++` doesn't confuse me at all. Having a function that expects no arguments and returns `this`, having that function accept an argument anyway and return something which is like, but isn't exactly, the argument - that makes no sense to me.

Comment: Updated it @NathanLong to show what `dis.call()` does.

Comment: 5++ behaves the same as in C language so nothing surprising. `this` is simply a pointer to an object so primitive types are converted implicitly. Why a function with no arguments couldn't have at least a context? The 1st argument of `call` or `bind` is used to set the context. Also, functions are closures which means they have access to more than just `arguments`

Answer (score 10):

The primitive values can't have property. But when you try to access to a property on primitive value, it transparently transtype to a temporary Number object.

So:

```
> function dis() { return this }
undefined
// Like five.dis(), so dis return the temporaty Number object and 
// reference it in five
> five = dis.call(5)
Number {[[PrimitiveValue]]: 5}

// Write the wtf attribut on the Number object referenced by five
> five.wtf = 'potato'
"potato"
// Read the wtf attribut on the Number object referenced by five
> five.wtf
"potato"

// Return 5*5 but dont change the reference of five
> five * 5
25
// Read the same wtf attribut on the Number object referenced by five
> five.wtf
"potato"

// Change the five reference to a new primitive value (5+1). Five
// reference a primitive now.
> five++
5

// Read the wtf attribut on a new temporary Number object construct from
// the primitive referenced by five. So wtf does not exist.
> five.wtf
undefined

// Write the wtf attribut on a new temporary Number object construct from
// the primitive referenced by five. But this object not referenced by
// five. It will be lost.
> five.wtf = 'potato?'
"potato?"

// Read the wtf attribut on a new temporary Number object construct from
// the primitive referenced by five. So wtf does not exist.
> five.wtf
undefined
> five
6
```

Answer (score 8):

Declare function `dis`. Function returns its context

```
function dis() { return this }
undefined
```

Call `dis` with context `5`. Primitive values are boxed when passed as context in strict mode ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode#Securing_JavaScript)). So `five` now is object (boxed number).

```
five = dis.call(5)
Number {[[PrimitiveValue]]: 5}
```

Declare `wtf` property on `five` variable

```
five.wtf = 'potato'
"potato"
```

Value of `five.wtf`

```
five.wtf
"potato"
```

`five` is boxed `5`, so it's number and object at the same time (5 * 5 = 25). It doesn't changes `five`.

```
five * 5
25
```

Value of `five.wtf`

```
five.wtf
"potato"
```

Unboxing `five` here. `five` now is just primitive `number`. It prints `5`, and then add `1` to `five`.

```
five++
5
```

`five` is primitive number `6` now, there are no properties in it.

```
five.wtf
undefined
```

primitives cannot have properties, you can't set this

```
five.wtf = 'potato?'
"potato?"
```

you can't read this, because it was not set

```
five.wtf
undefined
```

`five` is `6` because of post incrementing above

```
five
6
```

Answer (score 7):

First off it looks like this is being run through the nodejs console.

1.

```
    function dis() { return this }
```

creates the function dis(), but because it wasn't set as a `var` there was no value to return so `undefined` was the output, even though `dis()` was defined. On a sidenote, `this` wasn't returned because the function wasn't executed.

2.

```
    five = dis.call(5)
```

This returns javascript's `Number` object because you just set the function `dis()`'s `this` value to the primitive five.

3.

```
   five.wtf = 'potato'
```

The first returns `"potato"` because you just set the property `wtf` of `five` to `'potato'`. Javascript returns the value of a variable you set, making it easy to chain multiple variables and set them to the same value like this: `a = b = c = 2`.

4.

```
    five * 5
```

This returns `25` because you just multiplied the primitive number `5` to `five`. The value of `five` was determined by the value of the `Number` object.

5.

```
    five.wtf
```

I skipped this line before because I would be repeating it here.
It just returns the value of the property `wtf` that you set above.

6.

```
    five++
```

As @Callum said, `++` will convert the type to `number` from the same value from the object `Number {[[PrimitiveValue]]: 5}}`.

Now because `five` is a `number`, you can't set properties to it anymore until you do something like this:

```
    five = dis.call(five)
    five.wtf = "potato?"
```

or

```
    five = { value: 6, wtf: "potato?" }
```

Also note that the second way will have different behavior than using the first method because it is defining a generic object instead of the `Number` object that was created before.

I hope this helps, javascript likes to assume things, so it can get confusing when changing around from the `Number` object to a primitive `number`. 
You can check what type something is by using the `typeof` keyword, writing
        typeof five
after you initialize it returns `'object'`, and after you do `five++` it returns `'number'`.

@deceze describes the difference between the Number object and the primitive number extremely well.

Answer (score 6):

JavaScript scopes are made of Execution Contexts. Each Execution Context has a Lexical Environment (external/globally scoped values), a Variable Environment (locally scoped values), and a *this binding*.

The *this binding* is a very important part of the Execution Context. Using `call` is one way to alter the *this binding*, and doing so will automatically create an object to populate the binding with.

[**Function.prototype.call()** (from MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

> **Syntax**
> `fun.call(thisArg[, arg1[, arg2[, ...]]])`
>
> **thisArg**
> The value of this provided for the call to fun. Note that this may not be the actual value seen by the method: if the method is a function in non-strict mode code, null and undefined will be replaced with the global object and **primitive values will be converted to objects**. (emphasis mine)

Once it is evident that 5 is being converted into `new Number(5)`, the rest should be rather obvious. Note that other examples will also work so long as they are primitive values.

```js
function primitiveToObject(prim){
  return dis.call(prim);
}
function dis(){ return this; }

//existing example
console.log(primitiveToObject(5));

//Infinity
console.log(primitiveToObject(1/0));

//bool
console.log(primitiveToObject(1>0));

//string
console.log(primitiveToObject("hello world"));
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUyRV.png" />
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

### A couple of concepts explain what happens

`5` is a number, a primitive value

`Number {[[PrimitiveValue]]: 5}` is an instance of Number (let's call it object wrapper)

Whenever you access a property/method on a primitive value, the JS engine will create an object wrapper of the appropriate type (`Number` for `5`, `String` for `'str'` and `Boolean` for `true`) and resolve the property access/method call on that object wrapper. This is what happens when you do `true.toString()` for example.

When performing operations on objects, they are converted to primitive values (by using `toString` or `valueOf`) in order to resolve those operations - for example when doing

```
var obj = { a : 1 };
var string = 'mystr' + obj;
var number = 3 + obj;
```

`string` will hold the string concatenation of `mystr` and `obj.toString()` and `number` will hold the addition of `3` and `obj.valueOf()`.

### Now to put it all together

```
five = dis.call(5)
```

`dis.call(5)` behaves just like `(5).dis()` if `5` actually had the method `dis`. In order to resolve the method call, the object wrapper is created and the method call is resolved on it. At this point five points to an object wrapper around the primitive value 5.

```
five.wtf = 'potato'
```

Setting a property on an object, nothing fancy here.

```
five * 5
```

This is actually `five.valueOf() * 5` obtaining the primitive value from the object wrapper. `five` still points to the initial object.

```
five++
```

This is actually `five = five.valueOf() + 1`. **Before this line `five` holds the object wrapper around the value 5, while after this point `five` holds the primitive value `6`**.

```
five.wtf
five.wtf = 'potato?'
five.wtf
```

`five` is no longer an object. Each of those lines creates a new instance of Number in order to resolve the `.wtf` property access. The instances are independent, so setting a property on one will not be visible on another. The code is completely equivalent to this one:

```
(new Number(6)).wtf;
(new Number(6)).wtf = 'potato?';
(new Number(6)).wtf;
```